# How to recover this load value

Tags: string, get, position

I want create a script, running in a cron to perform a task that if some OpenVZ machine has a high load, it will be rebooted.

To do, I need get the last value of the CPU load of each VM. I get with this command:

vzlist -o ctid,laverage > loads.txt

```
  CTID       LAVERAGE
  1001 0.00/0.00/0.00
  1002 0.58/0.62/0.56
  1009 0.00/0.00/0.00
  1060 0.01/0.05/0.07
  1063 0.00/0.03/0.00
  1066 0.00/0.00/0.00
  1072 0.00/0.00/0.00
  1083 11.18/5.89/2.35
```

Now, I want select the 3th load value to put in a variable.

I have tried this code:

> cat loads.txt | while read line; do
>
> echo ${line:15:4}
>
> done

but I have a problem with the last line, because I get the value

/2.3

Can anybody help me to put in a variable the number after the last / ??

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
cat loads.txt | while read line; do 
  echo ${line} | cut -d'/' -f3;
done
```